# exclude posts with meta value empty wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have made a custom field "checkbox". I want to exclude posts only that have the checkbox checked.
I am not able to do so.
Here is the code that i am using

```
$args = array(
                'posts_per_page'=> -1,
                 'post_type' => 'latestnews',
                 'orderby'=> 'id',
                 'meta_key'=>'',
                 'meta_value'=>'',
                 'order'=> 'asc',
                );
            query_posts($args);
    $my_posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

So basically i want the posts only that doesn't have the meta key "sticky" set and meta value does not exists.
here my meta key is a checkbox and the value yes is stored in the database if i check the checkbox and nothing is stored in the database if i do not check the option.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$check_metakey = get_post_meta($post->ID, "sticky", true);
if($check_metakey !== '') :
?>
your article's template
<?php
endif;
?>
```

NOTE: All this INSIDE the while cycle.

Good luck! :)